# What is the optimal collection if the keys are sequential integers but not zero-based?

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary, collections

I am specifically referring to using years as keys, but the question applies to any n-based sequential index.

Let's say I'm looking at apple harvests by year. I want to access my data by year, like so:

```
var harvests = GetLast50YearsOfHarvestData();
//1991 was a great year for apples
harvests[1991].ApplesPicked ...
```

The obvious answer is to use a Dictionary.

```
var harvests = Dictionary<int, AppleHarvest>();
```

Yet I know that arrays are faster. Apple harvest software is normally very performance-tuned. I will not be searching, adding, or deleting from my collection. I will only ever be accessing by key.

```
AppleHarvest[] harvests;
...
harvests[24] //1991 was a great year for apples
harvests[49] //wait what year is this? 2017?
```

I know that my keys will always be sequential, without gaps, but working with an array requires extra logic to know what year the zero-based index corresponds to. My performance may still be superior, but I'd prefer to not have to deal with that extra layer.

What are the options for achieving essentially an n-based array?

Comment: It is never a good idea to use "magic numbers". Instead show explicitly how the number is calculated: `harvests[year - START_YEAR]`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'd write that up as an answer (note that a method is another way for DRY)

Comment: You could write a class that is intialized with the zero based index equivalent and then do all the back and forth math there and access it with your more meaningful indexes from outside.

Comment: The magic numbers are just for this example. I just wanted to clearly show that I'm referring to calendar year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own collection type:

```
public class SequentialKeyedCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private T[] _innerArray;
    private int _startIndex;

    public SequentialKeyedCollection(int startIndex, int length)
    {
        _innerArray = new T[length];
        _startIndex = startIndex;
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get => _innerArray[index - _startIndex];
        set => _innerArray[index - _startIndex] = value;
    }

    public int Length => _innerArray.Length;

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        int i = Array.IndexOf(_innerArray, item);
        if (i < 0) return i; // Not found.
        return i + _startIndex;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<T>)_innerArray).GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<T>)_innerArray).GetEnumerator();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is to use an array of AppleHarves, elements indexes indicate years:

```
AppleHarvest[] apples = new AppleHarvest[3000];

// 1991 was a great year for apples
apples[1991] = GetAppleHarvestForYear(1991);
```

Of course, there will be some unused year at the beginning of the array, but this overhead is really low.

Concerning algorithmic complexity, reading from an array is `O(1)` operation.
Reading from a dictionary is also `O(1)` operation, so the difference is only a constant multiplier, but arrays are faster.

Comment: I was unaware they were both O(1). I assumed that Dictionary would have worse performance. If that's true, then I should probably just stick with Dictionary?

Comment: @friggle O(1) just means that the performance doesn't change with the size of the collection.  There can still be a constant factor difference in access speed.  However, this starts to get into the realm of micro-optimization.  Don't optimize things until you've measured them and determined them to be a problem.  Just do whatever is easier to understand first.

Answer (score 0):

To get the zero-based index, you can subtract a "base year" from any given year:

```
harvest[year - START_YEAR]
```

This is more easily readable than using a "magic number" and also more flexible since `year` is now a variable. You can even take this a step further by encapsulating the array in a class and creating a getter method which takes the year as a parameter and internally does the subtraction and the array access.

Comment: Unless you are saying `year` as in "year 1", "year 2". Then you'd need to adjust your math. For a calendar year, the above is sufficient.

Comment: @KennethK. I don't understand your comment. If `START_YEAR == 1`, then my answer still adjusts the year to a zero-based index. Besides, the OP clearly uses calendar years as shown in their examples.

Comment: Agreed. I just meant that if `START_YEAR` was, for example, `2000`, and the programmer wants `year` to mean "year 1", then you simply need to do an addition rather than a subtraction. Regardless, what you have is fine.

Comment: @KennethK. If `year == 1` meaning 2001 from your example, then you use it directly. No need to add or subtract, either one.